# AngularJS: Neat way to print array as string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have a following array:

```
"cast": [
      {
        "name": "James Stewart"
      },
      {
        "name": "Kim Novak"
      },
      {
        "name": "Barbara Bel Geddes"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tom Helmore"
      }
    ]
```

What is the neat in AngularJS to to format it as:

```
James Stewart, Kim Novak, Barbara Bel Geddes, Tom Helmore
```

Is there a way to use `filter` or `formatter` so that I can neatly do it in template like:

```
<font class="authors-string">{{ object.cast | filter/formatter/? }}</font>
```

I think writing logic for this simple parsing in controller would clutter controller body.

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Just use `ng-repeat`: `<div ng-repeat="person in cast">{{ person.name }}</div>` edit: `<span>` might be better for you here

Comment: does `ng-repeat` not work?

Comment: For ng-repeat, how will I join the strings by comma?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a filter that extracts a certain prop from each array element, then joins them using a separator ([demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/OriDrori/1pgbwgtg/8/)):

```
app.filter('join', function () {
    return function join(array, separator, prop) {
        if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
            return array; // if not array return original - can also throw error
        }

        return (!angular.isUndefined(prop) ? array.map(function (item) {
            return item[prop];
        }) : array).join(separator);
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<p class="authors-string">{{ cast | join:', ':'name' }}</p>
```

If it is a flat array, you drop the 3rd parameter:

```
<p class="authors-string">{{ animals | join:', ' }}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, it simplified my code. But are there any dangers associated with using Array.prototype.map regarding compatibility?

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'ng-repeat' - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

An example would be:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
```

To add a comma on all but the last value:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... <span ng-if="!$last">, </span></div>
```

Comment: But how I'll insert joining commas in between items if I use ng-repeat?